# Conditional breakpoint in Visual Studio - condition using non basic data types

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

Is it true that the condition in a conditional breakpoint can only have the basic datatypes (i.e. `int`, `float`, `bool`, etc).
Say for example I have defined `NULL` for an object of a `class MyClass` as `NULL_OBJ`.
And I have in my code an object `MyClass myclassobject`.
Could I put a condition as `myclassobject==NULL_OBJ` in a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do not want to compare object pointers to null pointer, which is trivial; yes, you can put such a condition.

However, you need to `overload` equality operator `==` for related `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass()
        {
           someMember = 0; // let this be null object condition
        }
        MyClass(int member)
        {
           someMember = member; 
        }
        bool operator == (const MyClass &Ref) const 
        {
            return(this->someMember== Ref.GetMember());
        }

        const int GetMember() const
        {
            return(this->someMember);
        }

    private:
        int someMember;
};

#define NULL_OBJ MyClass()
```

By `#define NULL_OBJ MyClass()`, you can define a null object and compare any `MyClass` object with it.

(with the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/60744/))

Answer (score 0):

You can take the address of the objects and compare that as normal.